# Error while "make"ing OMNet5.4 in Win10 64bit (1803)

Tags: makefile, installation, simulation, omnet++

I did as the installation guide said:

1. "./configure", everything was fine;
2. "make", i got the following errors :

   `===== Compiling sim ====
   YACC: expr.y
   LEX: expr.lex
   MSGC: sim_std.msg
   make[2]: *** [Makefile:155：sim_std_m.cc] error 127
   make[1]: *** [Makefile:118：sim] error 2
   make: *** [Makefile:28：allmodes] error 2`

PS:

1. The MD5 of "omnetpp-5.4-src-windows.zip" checks out;
2. Already tried with WinRAR and 7-zip to unzip, got same errors at the same stage;
3. Full path does not contain any space;
4. Even tried to install "omnetpp-5.3-src-windows.zip", got same errors at the same stage;
5. Also tried to install omnet++ with and without JDK(Java SE 10.0.1) + Mingw(or cygwin) installed, got same errors at the same stage;
6. Even tried to update the MSYS2 inside the omnet directory, then "./configure; make clean; make", got same errors at the same stage;
7. Already disable the Windows Defender;
8. I do exactly as installation guide says: run "./configure", "make (clean)" and other things in "mingwenv.cmd".
9. also tried to enable gcc instead of clang, same error;

I don't know what to do.

-------update-------

I reset my Win10, and then, first thing to do is try to install OMNet after the OS "come alive". Finally, it is OK.

Sorry i did not try any further. Thank you all.

Comment: Try to disable real-time antivirus protection.

Comment: Do you run ./configure from a MinGW shell of your own, or do you start the "mingwenv" script from the OMNeT++ sources?

Comment: It seems like the message compiler is crashing. Could you try a 

`make clean` and then `make MODE=debug`

Also it's worth try to disable clang and try to use GCC for compilation. Change the PREFER_CLANG variable in configure.user and then run ./configure and then rebuild.